# How to pause in C?

Tags: c

I am a beginner of C. I run the C program, but the window closes too fast before I can see anything. How can I pause the window?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

you can put

```
getchar();
```

before the return from the main function. That will wait for a character input before exiting the program.

Alternatively you could run your program from a command line and the output would be visible.

Comment: Yes, then you just press any key to finish the program and close the window.

Comment: +1 for "run from the command line", which is a skill that is sorely lacking these days.

Comment: @John - agreed, especially if your program prints to the console, it would only make sense to run it from the command line.

Comment: It depends who you're distributing to. Would also be nice if you can detect the difference between a command line invocation vs double click and act accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to just **delay** the closing of the window without having to actually press a button (`getchar()` method), you can simply use the `sleep()` method; it takes the amount of **seconds** you want to sleep as an argument.

```
#include <unistd.h>
// your code here
sleep(3); // sleep for 3 seconds
```

References:
[sleep() manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html)

Answer (score 7):

Under POSIX systems, the best solution seems to use:

```
#include <unistd.h>

pause ();
```

If the process receives a signal whose effect is to terminate it (typically by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal), then `pause` will not return and the process will effectively be terminated by this signal. A more advanced usage is to use a signal-catching function, called when the corresponding signal is received, after which `pause` returns, resuming the process.

Note: using `getchar()` will not work is the standard input is redirected; hence this more general solution.

Answer (score 5):

Is it a console program, running in Windows? If so, run it from a console you've already opened. i.e. run "cmd", then change to your directory that has the .exe in it (using the cd command), then type in the exe name. Your console window will stay open.

Answer (score 4):

You could also just use `system("pause");`

Answer (score 3):

`getch()` can also be used which is defined in conio.h.

The sample program would look like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    //your code 
    getch();
    return 0; 
}
```

`getch()` waits for any character input from the keyboard (not necessarily enter key).

Comment: This is only on Windows.  Unix doesn't have conio.h

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a console window program, you can use system("pause");

Comment: @JerryJeremiah he said "windows". I think `pause` also works on Linux and  Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are on Windows. Instead of trying to run your program by double clicking on it's icon or clicking a button in your IDE, open up a command prompt, cd to the directory your program is in, and run it by typing its name on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Good job I remembered about DOS Batch files.
Don't need Getchar() at all.
Just write the batch file to change directory (cd) to the folder where the program resides.
type the name of the exe program and on the next line type pause.
example:

```
cd\
```

wallpaper_calculator.exe
pause

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the best at C and I'm kind of new; but here's what I would do.

If you want to press any key to continue/end the program. I'd create a void function pause().

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
    void pause() {
        system("pause>nul");
        return;
    }
    
    int main() {
        //your code here
        pause(); // you pause here
    }
```

For time delays between code, you can use sleep(), sleep(1) = 1-second delay, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux; getchar() is all you need.

If you are on Windows, check out the following, it is exactly what you need!

> **kbit() function**

- kbhit() function is used to determine if a key has been pressed or not.
- To use kbhit() in C or C++ prorams you have to include the header file "conio.h".

For example, see how it works in the following program;

```
//any_key.c

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

    //code here
    printf ("Press any key to continue . . .\n");
    while (1) if (kbhit()) break; 
    //code here 
    return 0;

}
```

When I compile and run the program, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayOCy.gif) is what I see.

Only when user presses just one key from the keyboard, *kbhit()* returns 1.