# How to stop my .exe from disappearing when using CMake

Tags: c, cmake, command-line-interface

I am using cmake to build my project from the command line. The problem is, as soon as the executable finishes running it disappear immediately and I have mere milliseconds the contents that are printed on screen. I can't read much in milliseconds. Is there anything I can do so that the console screen doesnt disappear as soon as it has finished executing?

here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(TotallyFree C)

add_executable(Acrolibre acrolibre.c)

set(LIBSRC acrodict.c acrodict.h)

add_library(acrodict ${LIBSRC})

add_executable(Acrodictlibre acrolibre.c)

target_link_libraries(Acrodictlibre acrodict)

set_target_properties(Acrodictlibre PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-DUSE_ACRODICT")
```

and here is my equivalent of main.cpp:

```
//#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifdef USE_ACRODICT
#include "acrodict.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //int waitTime = 10000000;
    const char* name;
#ifdef USE_ACRODICT
    const acroItem_t* item;
#endif

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: you need one argument\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s <name>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    name = argv[1];

#ifndef USE_ACRODICT
    //if(strcasecmp(name, "toulibre")==0){
    if(_stricmp(name, "toulibre")==0){
        printf("Toulibre is a French organization promoting FLOSS.\n");
    }
#else
    item = acrodict_get(name);
    if(NULL != item){
        printf("%s: %s\n", item->name, item->description);
    }else if(item = acrodict_get(name)){
        printf("<%s> is unknown maybe you mean:\n", name);
        printf("%s: %s\n", item->name, item->description);
    }
#endif
    else{
        printf("Sorry, I don't know: <%s>\n", name);
        //Sleep(waitTime);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //Sleep(waitTime);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see I even used Sleep() and #include to delay this shutting down of the console. But it doesn't work. Is there anything anyone can recommend?

Comment: Would a call to [`getchar`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getc) at the end of main function be enough?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869507/how-to-pause-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pause in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869507/how-to-pause-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the make files here. Your program exits, and the console window disappears. Try using `getch()` before returning from `main()` for the program to wait for any key before exiting. Or, you can run your program from a console.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with CMake, and everything to do with the way you're running your application.

When you double-click a console EXE in Windows, it opens a new console, runs the program, and closes the console, lie it should.

You have two options:

- Run the program from the command-line of an already open console (`cmd.exe`)
- Add this code to the end of `main`:

```
 printf("Press Enter to exit\n");
 getchar();
```

Comment: I tried this. The program runs and still disappears immediately