# How to add a Pause Function to Display Output?

Tags: c

I'm fairly beginning in C, and was working on an assignment that asks me to take user inputs between -50 and 100 and then calculate various characteristics of the numbers entered such as average, even/odd, etc. (the program will stop once -999 is entered). I am also supposed to have the program Pause and display the output, and once the user presses any key, the screen will clear and another number will be entered by the user.

Everything else is functioning properly, and the code so far looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    //used for math
    int i = 0;
    float num[100], sum = 0.0, average;
    //user input number
    float x = 0.0;
    //used to determine minimum and maximum numbers
    unsigned int min, max, buf;
    //used for determining prime number
    int flag;
    //for pause button
    char ch;

    while (1) {
        printf("%d. Enter number: ", i + 1); 
        scanf("%f", &x);
        //establish exit number
        if (x == -999)
            break;
        //make sure number is within range
        if (x >= -50 && x <= 100)
        {
            num[i] = x;
            sum += num[i];
            i++;
            //determin minimum and maximum
            if (x >= buf)
            {
                max = x;
            }
            if (x <= buf)
            {
                min = x;
            }
            buf = x;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("invalid number, must enter between -50 and 100\n");
        }
    }

    average = sum / i;

    //determine if prime num
    if (x / i == 0)
    {
       flag = 1;
    }

    //display output
    printf("\n Average = %.2f", average);
    printf("\n Sum = %.2lf", sum);
    printf("\n Numbers entered = %d", i);
    printf("\n The highest value entered : %u", max);
    printf("\n The lowest value entered : %u", min);
    if (x / 2 == 0)
        printf("\n%.2f is even.", x);
    else
        printf("\n%.2f is odd.", x);

    //determine prime number
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        printf("\n%.2f is a prime number.", x);
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        printf("\n%.2f is not a prime number.", x);
    }
    printf("\nThank you for using my program, have a nice day :)");

    return 0;
}
```

The pause button is the only thing that is not functioning properly. Would there be anyone that would know the answer of the best way to achieve the described pause button function? Thanks :)

Edit: I don't have the same problem as the "How to Pause in C" question, as I can see the output once -999 is entered, I just need to see the output one the screen is paused.

Comment: Please quote your assignment verbatim. I have no idea what "pause and display the output" could possibly mean for such program. C doesn't work with buttons anyway. You have an *input stream* that contains *characters*. Also please do yourself an enormous favour and **indent your program properly**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pause in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869507/how-to-pause-in-c)

Comment: @n.m verbatim task is: "The screen will PAUSE so the user can view the output. Once the user presses a key, the screen will clear and another number will be entered by the user"

Comment: "The screen will PAUSE" *when*?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic if, instead of exit code being 999, EOF was used instead. This would also allow a file of numbers to be piped in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getchar();` to pause your system. Once the user presses any key it will keep going. For clearing the screen you will need the `#include<conio.h>` library so that you can use the `clrscr();`

Here is a function for you to use:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void func() {
     getchar(); // Pauses the system until user presses a key
     clrscr();  // Clears the screen
}
```

You can just call the function for every time you want it to pause and clear the screen. Since `getchar();` will pause the system, it won't pass to the `clrscr();` unless the user presses a key.

Comment: Isn't `conio.h` only available on Windows ?

Comment: Because it uses streams, "clearing to screen" is not really defined in the C standard library; one could rely on the OS with `system`, an external library like `ncurses`, hack it by outputting `\n`, or system-specific libraries.

Comment: @Abra since many parts of the question is absent, I just assumed what he could use. Not saying this is exactly the right answer for the specific problem.

Comment: @Neil there definitely are multiple solutions for this question, the problem starts with C not being built for such requests. So all of the solutions are iffy. I just wrote what made most sense to me for the specific question.

Comment: Oops, was not commenting on your solution, but Abra's comment. `clrsrc` is one of the system-specific solutions that requires functions declared in `conio.h`; this solution works if you are on Windows. In buffered mode, `getchar`, which is in the `C` standard library, will wait until enter is pressed and might not be what you're looking for. Also in `conio.h` is `getch`, which might be a better fit if you're using it anyway.

Comment: @Neil oh I see, well you are completely right. As much as I can see, the user that asked this question is long gone from searching the result... Interesting how people get such assignments that they want to complete while being out of scope what the language is built for. I had the same issue at the beginning of my university years.